# Brightness controls on Oryx Pro with Nvidia on Loki

Tags: display, nvidia, laptop, brightness

I have a System 76 laptop with nvidia dedicated graphics and am having trouble with the brightness adjustment controls in Pantheon. I have installed the system76-driver-nvidia from their ppa.

I have tried to use the inotify/xbacklight based solution detailed here

http://sub-pop.net/post/fedora-23-on-system76-oryx-pro/

(which basically uses information from /proc and xbacklight to adjust the brightness) and it doesn't have any effect nor any helpful errors in the logs. This is how I get the display to work properly in GNOME3 on arch.

I am hoping that since one of the Elementary OS devs works at system 76 there is a solution that I just haven't found. Thank you in advance for any help that you can give!

Comment: It I add the backlight script to the startup applications then it seems to work. Though I am upset and cant figure out why it wont run under systemd

Comment: I will talk to hardware engineering today and see if they have any ideas. You can also open a ticket at system76.com with the same information posted here and see if the support team has any ideas. :)

Comment: I didn't think I was supposed to open tickets if I am not running the stock ubuntu. Will do.

Answer (score -1):

Slight edits to the original posts, got it to work systemd.

http://www.pynut.com/?p=386

Comment: Would you please expand on your answer in case the link goes down in the future?